# Why is the styling for my header affecting my content div?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code withe the complete code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Cilvako/rLt3mqrv/3/)

```
    <div id="header">

        <a href="index.html" id="logo">
             <h1 class="headings">THE 100 DAYS PROJECT</h1>

        </a>


        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
  </div>


 <div id="contact_container">

        <h3>General Informations</h3>

       <p>I am not currently looking for new design work, but I am available for speaking gigas and similar engagaments. If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to contact me!</p>

        <p>Please only use phone contact for urgent inquiries. Otherwise, twitter and email are the best way to reach me.</p>

        <h3>Contact info</h3>

                <ul class="contact_info">

                   <li>Phone</li>
                   <li>Email</li>
                   <li>Blog</li>
               </ul>
```

Although I haven't specified any styling for the list in the contact section, the bullets do not show up and the items are displayed in-line. From what I've seen, the line of code which affects this is:

```
          #header ul, li {
             display: inline-block;
               }
```

Why is this happening? I want my un ordered list in the contact section to display with bullets and have the items on different lines. Thx!

Comment: L3viathan answered the same way already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `#header ul, li` means `#header ul` or `li`, not `#header ul` or `#header li`.

Instead, write the selector as `#header ul, #header li`.

Comment: Oh... it's the coma again. Thank you :).